# Katalon WebUI.SetMaskedText() randomly wrapping text

Tags: testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I have a field in a popup to enter a phone number with masked text: "( _ _ _ ) _ _ _ - _ _ _ _".

(Masked text means that we are using jquery to automatically format the text being entered. You can learn more [here](https://salientprocess.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205662228-Masked-Text).) The underscores above are just to represent the spaces for the digits of the phone number. :)

## Results

The code randomly wraps the text when entering. I've tried using the string as '8015558245' and masked as '(801)555-8245', both wrap randomly with the results:

- (015)558-2458
- (155)582-4580
- (555)824-5801

The only suggestion I found on my many searches of the internets was to double click the element first, **which doesn't effect the results**. Each time I run the test in incognito mode. Occassionally it works, the rest of the time it fails.

## Code

Here is my code:

```
TestObject enterPhoneNumber = findTestObject('path/PhoneNumberObject')
WebUI.doubleClick(enterPhoneNumber)
WebUI.setMaskedText(enterPhoneNumber, '8015558245')
```

### Specs

I am using Katalon v5.9.1, but it wasn't working on earlier versions either.

Chrome is the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was a combination of things:

**First:** I needed to set the cursor to the left of the masked text right at the opening parenthesis. To guarentee this, I used the suggested clickOffset(enterPhoneNumber, 40, 5). [Thanks @Matt Mrse for your suggestion!]

This didn't fix the text wrapping when using WebUI.setMaskedText(..), but it allowed for the next part to work reliably, and that is:

**Second:** Text entered into the box manually was always entered in correctly. So instead of WebUI.setMaskedText(..), I just sent the whole string as if it were typed by using WebUI.sendKeys(..).

The final code, that worked reliably (all other previous attempts failed within 1-2 attempts) after five test runs in five different tests is this:

```
    WebUI.clickOffset(enterPhoneNumber, 40, 5)
    WebUI.sendKeys(enterPhoneNumber, '8015558245')
    WebUI.delay(1) //For humans to be able to see that text was entered correctly
```

**That's it!**

Hope this helps anyone else with this issue!

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be happening because `WebUI.doubleClick()` is targeting the middle of the element so it starts typing somewhere behind the ().

Maybe try using `WebUI.clickOffset(enterPhoneNumber,x,y)` with a small value of x and y (5 px for example - calculated from the top left corner of the element) so you are sure click will land somewhere near the first `(_ _ _` digit place.

Another option is using

```
WebUI.click(enterPhoneNumber)
WebUI.sendKeys(enterPhoneNumber, Keys.chord(Keys.HOME))
WebUI.setMaskedText(enterPhoneNumber, '8015558245')
```

with

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
```

imported.

Comment: These were great suggestions. Unfortunately, even with the cursor in the far left position, as soon as it starts to add the masked text it wraps it, unpredictably. I even added a delay betwen clicking and typing, but it still upredictably wraps. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! You were VERY helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are something you need to double check:
 - are the () be added automatically when you typing the phone number?
 - setMaskText() is used to enter text as '**************'

I am not sure if I understand the case clearly. Normally, I deal with this case by using sendKeys keyword, which will demostrate the typing action so the phone format can be added correctly.

Comment: To answer your question, this is a masked text box. That means that jquery is formatting the text. You can learn more [here](https://salientprocess.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205662228-Masked-Text).